# How country targeting works in Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I've read through Google Play Console support: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7550024?hl=en# and I'm still not sure if I can do the following:

- I have a 1.0 version in Production released to all countries
- I have a 2.0 version in Beta released to all countries
- I want to release 2.0 to production but to all countries excepting USA. However, I want to keep USA users to be able to download 1.0

I'm not sure about the 1.0 Production release to be available in the USA.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a staged rollout: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149 (see section "Release a staged roll-out to specific countries")